# 月間100万PVのサイト運営に適したサーバ構成は？

Tags: wordpress, サーバー管理, capacity-planning

最近、サーバ構築のアルバイトを始めたのですが、その研修中に月間100万PVのメディアサイトを運営するにあたってのサーバ構成についての提案をしなさいという課題を出されました。メディアサイトの設定としては以下のとおりです。

・月間１００万PV
・Yahoo、スマートニュース、グノシー等に不定期に取り上げられる。
・現在はさくらインターネットのビジネスプロ１台を借りている。
・アクセス集中時にWEBページがうつらないことがある。
・メディアサイト運営企業のWeb担当者はサーバに関しては素人同然。オンプレミス型は不可能。
・LAMP環境でWordpressを用いて運営している。
・1ページあたりのサイズは1MB程度
・一日のうち昼と夜の計6時間にアクセスが集中する。

僕としてはクラウドサーバへの移設を進めていく方針で行こうと考えているのですが、
そのさいのCPUやメモリ構成などはどのように判断すれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: アプリの構成情報も無いと、回答は難しいと思います。

Comment: @himakuma アプリとはどのようなものをさしていらっしゃるのでしょうか？
モバイルアプリということでしょうか？

Comment: サーバーに乗せるアプリケーションのことです。今回の場合だとWEBページをなにで作っているか、DBは何を使用しているかとかですね。

Comment: @himakuma 設定としては、LAMP環境で構築していて、Wordpressを用いて運営しているという状態です。

Comment: １ページあたりのサイズ等情報を追記しました。

Answer (score 5):

サイジングは経験が物を言うと思いますので、どんなアプリでどんな構成でという情報があれば、知見のある人からの回答があるかもしれません。

仮にWordpressのブログサイトで月間100万PVくらいなら、2コア、4GBくらいかなぁとか思いますが、載せるアプリやコンテンツにより変わりますので一概には言えません。

また、クラウドでということでしたら、CPUやメモリ構成はお決まりのパターンからの選択になると思いますが、変更は容易ですので 最適なサイズが分からない場合は、小さめではじめて 負荷状況を確認しながら スケールアップ&スケールダウンをしながら最適な構成を探すほうが現実的です。

というのも、前もって必要なサーバーリソースを見積もっても、所詮は仮想マシンですから、他のユーザの影響を受けて、期待通りの性能が出ないこともあります（お金を出せばH/Wを専有出来たりもしますが）ので、システムの拡張性を考慮した運用が必須だと思います。

Web担当者が素人同然であれば、出来るだけ自動化するのが親切でしょう。例えばWebとDBを分離して、Webの性能不足は自動的にスケールアウトし解決。DBの性能不足はアラーム等で通知して、スケールアップで対応などすると良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 4):

回答のためにより詳しい要件や1PVあたりの負荷などの情報が必要であることは他の回答者の方々の通りです。

ひとつ言えることとして、質問中に出てきていない要素として、ロードバランサの導入は必須かと思います。例えばAWSであればElastic Load Balancingですね。

> ・Yahoo、スマートニュース、グノシー等に不定期に取り上げられる。

ということだと、1台のサーバーのスペック増強では限界があり、結局アクセスが集中した時に対処しきれずページの閲覧ができなくなる、という問題は解決できないかと思います。

ユーザーからのURLなどの見た目は全く変えずにサーバーを増やしたり減らしたりするため、クラウド・オンプレに限らずロードバランサを入れ、その後ろにサーバーを少なくとも2台用意しておくのが安全かと思います。（アクセス増でなくてもサーバーがダウンすることは珍しくないため）